# Why Vue can't watch the data change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i want the function:createComparation work when tableRowName change,but acturely when tableRowName change , it didnt works,vue follows;
createComparation is another function which didnt define by vue but only by javascript

```
const selectedRight =Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            tableRow:0,
            tableRowName:[],
            stockName:[],
            rectWidth:40,
            rectHeight:5,
        }
    },
    watch: {
        tableRowName(newtable,oldtable){
            console.log(1)
            createComparation()
        },
        immediate:true,
        stockName(){
            changeTip()
        },
        
    },
    methods:{

    }
}).mount('#selectedRight')
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools for errors when you load the page and when it's running ... why is there a watch for `immediate` with no function for that watcher? just the value `true` ... is the valid vue?

Comment: well，im sry but can you just show me how to do,I changed my vue 2to3 just for some function ,but the watch didnt work, the immediate i also cant understand how it did something

Comment: you've done the watch on `tableRowName` correctly as far as I can see ... you can see the browser console, I cant. so, no I can't "just show you how to do it", since you've "done it correctly" and only you can debug it

Comment: as for that `immediate: true` watcher - you must have put it there for a reason, it's your code after all

Comment: the console.log(1) didnt work ,but i know the tableRowName is change, the browser developer tools say it changes from  proxy{} to proxy{0:'xxxxxx'}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in case of **tableRowName** contain objects then you have to use

> deep:true

```
watch: {
        tableRowName(newtable,oldtable){
            console.log(1)
            createComparation()
        },
        immediate:true,
        deep: true,
        stockName(){
            changeTip()
        },
        
    },
```

but i think you are updating the array without reactive manner, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.

> vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

When you modify the length of the array, e.g.

> vm.items.length = newLength

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }
})
vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
```

Comment: thank you , acturely when i push something to tableRowName it cant work,but if i change it into other type like '1',it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess whatching array might be the issue. You can try this:

```
computed: {
    rowNames() {
        return this.tableRowName;
        // if the line above doesn't work:
        return this.tableRowName.join();
    }
},
watch: {
    rowNames(newtable,oldtable){
        createComparation()
    },
```

Comment: thank you but i've discovered that when i push something to the tableRowName ,it wont work ,but when i change the tableRowName directly to 1(for example), it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. You need to define the handler as an object for the property you're trying to watch and set `immediate: true`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tableRow: 0,
      tableRowName: [],
      stockName: [],
      rectWidth: 40,
      rectHeight: 5,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tableRowName: {
      handler(newtable) {
        console.log('Calling createComparation function');
        console.info(newtable);
      },
      immediate: true
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="tableRowName.push(Math.random())">Trigger change manually again</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The watch method definition is wrong. When you need to use immediate, you have to put you function body into handler property.

For example,

```
 watch: {
  tableRowName: {
    handler: function() {

    },
    immediate: true
  }
        
  },
```

Comment: thank you ,i did it and also cant get the right way, i've discovered that when i change the address of tablerowname can it watch and work .or if i push something it cant work .the immediate what i put means nothing acturely